# How to write a 3 channel image into a tiff file?

Tags: python, numpy, tiff

I don't find any clear explanation of how to make a 3 channel image with tifffile. I tried (all values are between 0 and 1)

```
image = [(0.5,0.2145,0), (1,0.214568,0.324586).... ]
side = int(len(image)**(1/2))
R,G,B = zip(*image)
R = np.array(R).reshape((side,side))
G = np.array(G).reshape((side,side))
B = np.array(B).reshape((side,side)) 

tiff.imsave("./TIFFs/%s_%s"%(data_class,data_id)+'.tiff', np.concatenate((R,G,B)) )
```

but what i get is 3 greyscale images one on top of the other representing the values R,G,B. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnNvs.jpg)

my goal is to get an RGB like image but with the floating point precision of tiff

Comment: It seems that your TIFF is stored with PlanarConfiguration = 2 ("planar") instead of PlanarConfiguration = 1 ("chunky"). See the TIFF 6.0 specification, page 38, for a technical explanation: https://www.itu.int/itudoc/itu-t/com16/tiff-fx/docs/tiff6.pdf I don't know the TIFF library you're using - maybe there are some options to change the PlanarConfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

I emailed Christoph Gohlke, the developer of Tifffile.py and heres his answer

```
E.g. tifffile.imsave('rgb.tif', numpy.zeros((256, 256, 3), 'uint16'))
```

For some reason it didn't work using a (n,n,3) shape worked perfectly (3,n,n) shaped numpy array instead.
Note : the RGB values are integers in the range [0,65535] so it still looses a good deal of float point precision.

Comment: numpy.zeros(shape, dtype=float, order='C')

    Return a new array of given shape and type, filled with zeros. ????